# Data Factory MSI authentication with Azure Event Hub through Web Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-eventhub

I am trying to send messages to an Event Hub through Data Factory's Web activity.

My Data Factory is set up with a system assigned managed identity (MSI), and that identity has been given the "Azure Event Hubs Data Sender" role on the Event Hubs Namespace (RBAC / IAM).

The Web activity is set up as follows:

```
{
    "name": "Send to Event Hub",
    "type": "WebActivity",
    "dependsOn": [],
    "policy": {
        "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
        "retry": 0,
        "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
        "secureOutput": false,
        "secureInput": false
    },
    "userProperties": [],
    "typeProperties": {
        "url": "https://<eventhubnamespace>.servicebus.windows.net/<eventhub>/messages?timeout=60&api-version=2014-01",
        "method": "POST",
        "body": {
            "DeviceId": "dev-01",
            "Temperature": "37.0"
        },
        "authentication": {
            "type": "MSI",
            "resource": "https://servicebus.azure.net"
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems that the request is always unauthorized. The web activity fails with the following message:

```
{
    "errorCode": "2108",
    "message": "Invoking Web Activity failed with HttpStatusCode - 'Unauthorized'.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Event Hub",
    "details": []
}
```

I also tried specifying the Content-Type header according to the [send event REST API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/send-event), but it made no difference.

According to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/get-azure-active-directory-token#send-messages-to-a-queue), it should be possible to authenticate against Event Hub using a Service Principal with OAuth2.0 Bearer token. My understanding is that ADF's MSI is no different than a Service Principal, except that I don't have to manage the secrets and tokens on my own. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you able to capture the token and check claims in it?

Comment: @SerkantKaraca I'm not sure how I would go about that in ADF, since the Web Activity automatically requests a token when using MSI authentication: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-web-activity#managed-identity